AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request on angular UI
I am getting this error when running my angular code on local the


I have checked my logout url is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logoutsession/  and my redirect url is "redirectUri": "https://127.0.0.1:8007"

@Arjun Dhilod  https://127.0.0.1:8007 change this url to localhost in the browser.

@Arjun Dhilod Are you using Azure Ad?

"msalConfig": {
"auth": {
"clientId": "bac70d6f-a74c-41ea-9fd8-04ded9e819b2",
"authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/c3e32f53-cb7f-4809-968d-1cc4ccc785fe",
"redirectUri": "https://127.0.0.1:8007"
},
"cache": {
"cacheLocation": "localStorage",
"storeAuthStateInCookie": false
}
}, here is code i am using for local

@AsleshaKantamsetti yes i am using AzureAD

@ArjunDhilod Change this 127.0.0.1 to localhost

@Cuzy this is wrong message, i have not done any code change still getting same error., Few days back my code is working okey , but since last week i am facing this issue

@AsleshaKantamsetti i have done changes as u suggested "redirectUri": "https://localhost:8007" but no luck.

@ArjunDhilod If possible, share your complete code.

@ArjunDhilod Did you change it in both code and browser?

{
"msalConfig": {
"auth": {
"clientId": "bac50d6f-a74c-41ea-8fd8-04ded9e819b4",
"authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/c3e32f53-cb7f-4809-968d-1cc4ccc785fe",
"redirectUri": "https://localhost:8007"
},
"cache": {
"cacheLocation": "localStorage",
"storeAuthStateInCookie": false
}
},
"protectedResourceMap": [["https://localhost:44313", ["api://bac50d6f-a74c-41ea-8fd8-04ded9e819b4/user_impersonation"]]]
}

@AsleshaKantamsetti issue is resolved Thank you for your help

As I mentioned in the comments, I used the redirect URI "http://localhost:4200" in my code and was able to successfully log in and log out with Azure AD without any issues.
Below is my Code.
src/app/module.ts_  :
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MsalModule, MsalService, MSAL_INSTANCE } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { IPublicClientApplication, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: '<client_ID>', 
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_ID>', 
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200' 
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
  });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    MsalService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


Output  :
It runs successfully as below:



Next, I click on the  Logout  button, and it shows my account to logout as below:


There are several steps are involved

I have added my self on AAD group.
Changed Logout URL on azure.
changed  127.0.0.1 to localhost.

